# Get notification (alert) from Mac when power charger is disconnected

Tags: macos, mac, battery, notifications, charging

I want my Mac to make a sound when the power charger is disconnected; similar (or different) to the one it does when it is connected.

I tried [this post](https://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/get-power-cable-connected-disconnected-alert-on-macos/) but did not work.
I used this one by @trane-francks [from stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368055/set-audio-alarm-for-when-charger-is-disconnected)  the problem is  I don't know how to make it stop altering if its on battery mode (unless I do `launchctl unload /Users/max/Library/LaunchAgents/batt.plist` in the Terminal).

This is the batt.sh in ~/Library/Scripts

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  if $(pmset -g batt | head -n 1 | grep -q "Battery"); then
      afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Funk.aiff;
      sleep 30;
  fi
sleep 0.1;
done
```

This is the .plist  file in  ~/Library/LaunchAgents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>batt</string>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>/Users/max/Library/Scripts/batt.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use a commercial tool, [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager) can do what you need.

Power Manager registers a notification with macOS's IOKit for changes to power sources. When a power source changes, Power Manager is notified and can determine if any events are interested in the specific change. This approach is more efficient that polling the state every thirty seconds.

With this approach, you can reduce your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Funk.aiff
```

To create a power source triggered event, see [How to Run a Command When Switching to Battery Power](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2011-07-12-how-to-run-a-command-when-switching-to-battery-power/):

[image: Power Manager on macOS - run a acript on switch to battery]

I work on Power Manager, so feel free to ask technical questions.

Comment: Just to put it out there... mostly if someone reading this already has it, this can also be done using [Keyboard Maestro (v.10)](https://wiki.keyboardmaestro.com/trigger/Power_Status_Changed). I can't really recommend it for everyone because it's more expensive, but it _should_ have almost the same functionality plus more.

Comment: Dude @graham-miln , I can run the script without buying your app; you are literally selling me a my .plist code! **The script is the problem not how to run it!** please

Comment: No, Emphatically No,  your app just run my crappy script that repeats itself in a loop; here is a video, featuring my daughter :)    https://youtu.be/ivyUQiL7GgI